# Error while using Decimal value in dynamic SOQL where clause

Tags: apex

```
String query = 'Select Id,Email,Name FROM Contact Where';
String clause = 'Mobile__c = '+accountCreate1.Custmobile__c;
List<Contact> conList = Database.query(query+clause);
```

Here account is Account object,but getting -  System.QueryException: Variable does not exist: accountCreate1.Custmobile__c

Comment: Why are you even using a dynamic query here?

Comment: actually this is a small part of my code , i have written a general function for quering objects  but  i'am getting error while using decimal field in where clause. (Custmobile__c is a number field)

Comment: We're probably going to need more context here to be able to provide any help. About the only thing that I'm seeing is that you never attach your 'clause' to your query before trying to run it (and `Custmobile__c` is probably a string, which I think you'd need to wrap in escaped single quotes in your query). Are you certain that `accountCreate1` is an `Account`? Where is it defined? That aside, I agree with Adrian here. Without additional context, the dynamic query here is unnecessary and is only causing you trouble.

Comment: Sorry , corrected. Yes accountCreate1  is an account.

Comment: String clause = 'Mobile__c =\' '+accountCreate1.Custmobile__c + '\'' ;

Comment: You seem to have missed the rest of my comment. I could provide suggestions on how to improve your code, but **the error you're seeing cannot be resolved with the information you've provided so far**. We need more context for the code snippet you've provided.

Comment: @Derek F , in my class i need to fetch contact multiple times , so i created a method in which i pass the 'WHERE' parameter as argument and fetch contact. It is working for other fields but not working for date and decimal fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Salesforce, Long `Integer` values are passed as a 32 bit integer into the query, unless you explicitly tell it to use a `Double`. Because of this, the maximum number you can query is limited by the maximum size of a 32 bit integer 2,147,483,647.

Below is the scenario which I tested on my Developer org. Both `Contact` and `light002__Deal_Action__c` has custom Mobile field defined as `Number (10,0)`. I'm trying to retrieve `light002__Deal_Action__c` by building query dynamically and using `light002__Mobile__c` field on `Contact`.

**Refer below code**:

```
Contact con = [SELECT id,light002__Mobile__c FROM Contact WHERE id='0032800001DxCOj'];
Decimal phoneNumber = con.light002__Mobile__c.setScale(1);
System.debug('phoneNumber:'+phoneNumber);
String body = 'Select id, Name FROM light002__Deal_Action__c WHERE ';
String clause = 'light002__Deal_Phone__c = '+phoneNumber;
System.debug('Query::'+body+clause);
String finalQuery = body+clause;
List<light002__Deal_Action__c> lst = Database.query(finalQuery);
System.debug('Size::'+lst.size());
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks  @Rohit Mourya , that worked , didnt knew that we need to do setScale.

Answer (score 1):

So there is a hidden Gem in Dynamic SOQL , you can actually use dynamic variable with it.

That being said you can do something like this.

```
String mobileNumber = accountCreate1.Custmobile__c;
List<Contact> contacts = Database.query('SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Mobile__c =:mobileNumber');
```

Please note the variable is actually inside the string, and the Database.query method automatically does the proper binding for it.

Comment: N.B. to @rohitc - the bind variable can not use dot notation, e.g `:a.b`

Comment: @Avidev9 , i had tried that but getting the same exception

Comment: then probably your code is not structured the way it should be, probably accountCreate1 is not accessible by the code. or there is datatype mismatch between Mobile__c and Custmobile__c @RohitC

Comment: @Avidev9 , accountCreate1  is accessible & datatypes are matching.Thanks , problem is solved now.